# Linear programming: Range of subgradients of linear functions maximized at a point

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, polytopes

Consider any non-empty compact convex feasible set defined by linear inequalities in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Clearly, this feasible set is a convex polytope, say $P = \{x \in [0,1]^n: A_i^T x \geq0, B_j^T x = 0 \;for\;i \in \{1,\cdots,I\}, j \in \{1,\cdots,J\}\}$. It has a finite set of, say, $K$ extreme points. Now consider the set of all possible linear functions on $\mathbb{R}^n, f(x) = V^Tx$. I fix a particular extreme point $X$ of $P$ such that at least one inequality constraint hold with equality at $X$.
and find out what is the set of subgradients $V$ for which $X$ is a solution to the linear program $max \; V^Tx,\;s.t.\; x \in P$. It is my understanding that it should be the convex hull of the gradients of all the hyperplanes $A_i^Tx=0$ which intersect at $X$.

First of all, is this correct?

Secondly, I'm confused about a few things. Since the boundary hyperplanes are all of the form $A_ix \geq 0$, and the same goes for $V^Tx$, any positive scalar multiple of $A_i$ or $V$ also works as the gradient of $A_ix = 0$ (same for $V^Tx$). So how to construct the aforementioned convex hull through taking convex combinations? If any kind of normalization (like normalize 2-norm to 1) is the correct way, is it unique, or we can do it in other ways also (e.g. fix one of the coordinates at 1)?

Edit: I have added more relevant details, thanks to suggestions of user LinAlg.

Comment: Your right-hand side is $0$, that means that $x=0$ is feasible and that $P$ is a cone. The only extreme point is $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add - there are some additional equality costraints. Have edited accordingly. Thank you for your input.

Comment: that does not affect my comment (and you could model an equality constraint as two inequalities)

Comment: $P$ is also the subset of a compact set $[0,1]^n$. I have now added this (admittedly, crucial) detail. Apologies again. This will create additional extreme points.

Comment: You could just summarize $P$ as $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+ : Ax \leq b\}$. The rest of your answer should now contain something with $[0,1]^n$ and $B_j$.

Comment: Can you tell me if it is true that the set of gradients $V$ for which $X$ is a solution to the linear program is = the convex hull of the gradients of all the hyperplanes $A^T_ix=0$ which intersect at $X$?